# mingw 5.2 strange message with std::string

Tags: c++, mingw32

a program with std::string anywhere will compile fine, but when run it fails with the message

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll.

I cannot find more information on it though, how can I remedy this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure the libstdc DLL(s) are compiled with the same version of your compiler as the application?

Comment: Did you try it on another installation? Could be a corrupted installation?

Comment: @A.S.H I'll try that. now that I look at it it's a bit different than the usual one so I'm remedying that now to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

turns out I had the wrong compiler, I needed 4.8 from the other MinGW